# How to use lerp() method in flutter and what are the use cases?

Tags: flutter

I actually came across the lerp function in many of the Flutter animations. I studied about linear interpolation. But I wonder how it's used in flutter and what are its use cases. could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It linearly interpolates between two values, for example:

```
var color = Color.lerp(Colors.white, Colors.black, 0.5);
var value = lerpDouble(10, 20, 0.5); // 15
```

The `color` here would have a middle value between white and black.

Comment: yeah I have tried it....but nothing happens when I provide it in a color property  except the middle value of those color in painted .. for example: Container(color: Color.lerp(Colors.white, Colors.black, 0.5)).   sorry if I am wrong... I don't properly get its usage. I actually saw a video that lerp will linearly animate between the start and end values. Is it used in animating widget properties

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is generally used in animation, for instance, you can start an animation using `AnimationController.forward()` and then you can use `Container(color: Color.lerp(Colors.white, Colors.black, _controller.value)` simple!

Comment: @iDecode Does this mean we don't have to use `Tween<double>` if we're using lerp?

Comment: @shadow-recruit I'm assuming you're asking it for `Tween`'s `transform` property. `Tween` is more flexible than lerp, but here between `lerpDouble` and `Tween<double>`, you can use either of them.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use it to animate color during dragging on tab view.

[image: btn]

```dart
var unselectedColor = Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor;
var selectedColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

Color color;

bool isSelected = itemIndex == tabController.index;
int currentIndex = tabController.index;

double offset = tabController.offset;

bool dragToRight = offset > 0;

if (dragToRight) {
  if (itemIndex >= currentIndex && itemIndex <= currentIndex + 1) {
    color = isSelected
        ? Color.lerp(selectedColor, unselectedColor, offset)
        : Color.lerp(unselectedColor, selectedColor, offset);
  }
} else {
  if (itemIndex >= currentIndex - 1 && itemIndex <= currentIndex) {
    color = isSelected
        ? Color.lerp(selectedColor, unselectedColor, -offset)
        : Color.lerp(unselectedColor, selectedColor, -offset);
  }
}
```

Comment: not the answer we wanted but the answer we needed. thanks.

Comment: can you share full code?

Comment: @AbdolHussainMozaffari https://gist.github.com/theachoem/d92b0ec4d0b23df7678e13aa0145b623